# CMD command to copy only files and not folders in a folder tree

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's assume the following folder structure:

> ```
> c:\tab\file1.txt
> c:\tab\insidetab1\file2.txt
> c:\tab\insidetab2\file3.txt
> c:\tab\insidetab3\insidetab4\file4.txt
> ```

I want to copy only files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`, `file4.txt` to some destination. Basically I want to remove all folders and keep only the files. Is it even possible?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Are you really working with **MS-DOS**, the OS from the 1980??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy all files that match the pattern file*.txt in C:\Tab to C:\Newtab.

```
 for /R C:\tab %%G in (file*.txt) do copy %%G C:\newtab\
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Working as expected!!